# python, mechanize - open a text file with mechanize

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I am learning mechanzie. I am trying to open a text file , the link that you would click on says
Text (.prn)
One problem i am having is there is only 1 form on this page and the file is not in the form.
Another problem for me is there are a couple Text files on this page, but they all have the same name 
Text (.prn). So i guess i need to get to the first one and open it. One thing that makes the text file I am trying to open unique is that it seems to be named

Summary , maybe i can use this to open it and 
then use br.form.find_control(    or maybe i can use:   br.click_link , if i can find some way to direct mechanize to open the first one titled "Summary"

The webpage I am on is:
http://www.treasurydirect.gov/govt/reports/pd/mspd/2013/2013_feb.htm

here is the section of the html where the text file is i want to open in mechanize:

```
</div>
<!-- END LOCALNAV --> 
    <!-- BEGIN CONTENT -->
    <div id="content">
        <h1>February 2013</h1>
        <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="content" -->
        <ul>
            <li>Summary
                <ul>
                    <li><a      href="/govt/reports/pd/mspd/2013/opds022013.pdf">Adobe Acrobat (.pdf)</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/govt/reports/pd/mspd/2013/opds022013.prn">Text (.prn)</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>STRIPS
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/govt/reports/pd/mspd/2013/opdr022013.pdf">Adobe Acrobat (.pdf)</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/govt/reports/pd/mspd/2013/opdr022013.xls">Excel 5.0/95 (.xls )</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/govt/reports/pd/mspd/2013/opdr022013.prn">Text (.prn)</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Entire MSPD
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/govt/reports/pd/mspd/2013/opdx022013.xls">Excel File for Primary Dealers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/govt/reports/pd/mspd/2013/opdm022013.pdf">Adobe Acrobat (.pdf)</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/govt/reports/pd/mspd/2013/opdm022013.xls">Excel 5.0/95 (.xls)</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/govt/reports/pd/mspd/2013/opdm022013.prn">Text (.prn)</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <p>Note: To read or print a PDF document, you need the Adobe Acrobat Reader (v5.0 or higher) software installed on your computer. You can download the Adobe Acrobat Reader from the <a href="/exit.htm?http://get.adobe.com/reader/">Adobe website</a>.</p>
        <p>Note: If you need <a href="/helpdownload.htm">help downloading...</a></p>
        <!-- InstanceEndEditable --> </div>
    <!-- END CONTENT --> 
    <!-- BEGIN SUBLOCALNAV -->
<div id="right">
```

here is my code so far starting on the page before the one the text file is on:

```
       br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_equiv(False)
br.open(site)
print 'br.title',br.title()
allforms = list(br.forms())
br.form = allforms[0]
br.follow_link(text_regex="February", nr=0)
#br.click_link(text='February', nr=0) # this works to

#next page
print br.title()
allforms = list(br.forms())
print allforms
br.form = allforms[0]
getstuff=br.click_link(text="Text (.prn)", nr=0) # this works to
csvData=getstuff.readlines()  # this is where is get error
```

here is my traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "treasury2.py", line 56, in <module>
csvData=getstuff.readlines()
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_urllib2_fork.py", line 173, in __getattr__
raise AttributeError, attr
AttributeError: readlines
```

I am using mechanize , BeautifulSoup ,urllib , urllib2 and python27

Please give me some help or even a hint on what  you think i should use to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right after `getstuff=br.click_link(text="Text (.prn)", nr=0)`, instead of your <s>csvData=getstuff.readlines()</s>, you should call:

```
br.open(getstuff)
csvData = br.response().read()
```

In case you need to do anything else with the previous page (i.e., **2013_feb.htm**), call:

```
br.back()
```

which will bring `br` back to the same state as right before the `br.open`.