# Formatting data from Text (.prn) file

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I am trying to figure the best way to handle the following data. I am scraping a site and using a Text (.prn)  file (a file for printing, this is the file with the data on I want, I think this would be better than the Adobe Acrobat file) to collect data from. My problem is when I bring the data into python: the data is just coming in vertical down the screen one letter at a time, so even though there are multiple rows this data is just streaming in on one column. I wonder if someone would know how to make the data come in, in  a more "traditional" way where I can bring in row[0], row [1] etc....
Here is my code in case it helps (you can also see some of the other functions I tried).

```
import os
import urllib
import urllib2
import string
import sys
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import mechanize
from numpy import*
import datetime
import traceback
from pylab import*
site="http://www.treasurydirect.gov/govt/reports/pd/mspd/mspd.htm"

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_equiv(False)
br.open(site)
print 'br.title',br.title()
allforms = list(br.forms())
br.form = allforms[0]
br.follow_link(text_regex="February", nr=0)
#br.click_link(text='February', nr=0) # this works to

#next page
print br.title()
allforms = list(br.forms())
print allforms
br.form = allforms[0]   
getstuff=br.click_link(text="Text (.prn)", nr=0) # this works to
#getstuff= br.click_link(text="Adobe Acrobat (.pdf)", nr=0)  Adobe Acrobat (.pdf)

br.open(getstuff)


csvData=br.response().read() # use read to BeautifulSoup(x)
#site = BeautifulSoup(csvData)
#print site
for row in csvData:
 print row[0]
```

Here is the exact site page where the text (.prt) file is at:
http://www.treasurydirect.gov/govt/reports/pd/mspd/2013/2013_feb.htm

I am trying to handle the data in the Text (.prn)  file  under SUMMARY.
please give advice on best way to handle the data.

I am using python27, mechanize, beautiful soup and urllib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading a text file with *beautiful soup* seems to give you back a single string in csvData, not a list of rows as you expect. So iterating on a string returns you a single char at every iteration step. This is why it seems that your text in transposed to single column.

Firstly, you don't seems to need *beautiful soup* at all! you are retrieving a textfile, not an HTML file. *Beautiful Soup* is an HTML/XML parser. Also *mechanize* seems unnecessary to me (I've seen [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15487772/python-mechanize-open-a-text-file-with-mechanize) but really, you do not need to parse the HTML page to discover the link, since you already know the final url).

To me you should split the algorithm in three parts:

- retrieve text as a list of rows
- remove unnecessary rows
- format your rows in order to fit your purposes

your question seems related mostly to the first part, but since you are asking also for advices on how to retrieve the final data I suppose you'll need the other two as well :)

Here is my suggestion: let's start defining three functions, one for each part of the algorithm...

```
import urllib2, re

def get_data_text(month, year):
    """given a month and a year, this method returns the raw data file (as a list of rows)"""
    url_pattern = 'http://www.treasurydirect.gov/govt/reports/pd/mspd/{year:4d}/opds{month:02d}{year:4d}.prn'
    url = url_pattern.format(month=month, year=year)
    source = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    data = source.readlines()
    source.close()
    return data


def keep_only_interesting_rows(data, interesting_rows):
    """filter data rows in order to keep only the ones that start with strings in interesting_rows list"""
    return [line for line in data if any([line.strip().startswith(ir) for ir in interesting_rows])]


def convert_data_to_dict(data):
    """converts every row in data to a dictionary element """
    return {re.sub('\.*\s*$', '', el[0:46]).strip():(int(el[47:63].replace(',','')), int(el[69:90].replace(',','')), int(el[95:115].replace(',',''))) for el in data}
```

So now I've defined three functions, one for each part in my proposed solution.

---

How to use these functions? here is an example:

```
interesting_rows = ['Bills', 'Notes', 'Total Public Debt Outstanding']  # add the initial part of any row you are interested at (without leading spaces)

mytext = get_data_text(2, 2013)  # gets the text for feb, 2013 as rows
data = keep_only_interesting_rows(mytext, interesting_rows)  # filter rows
final_data = convert_data_to_dict(data)  # convert remaining rows into a dict

print final_data
print final_data['Bills'][2]  # this gives you the third column


# >>> {'Notes': (7416574, 5888, 7422462), 'Bills': (1738404, 3546, 1741950), 'Total Public Debt Outstanding': (11822436, 4864853, 16687289)}
# >>> 1741950
```

---

if you want, for whatever reason, access a precise row in your initial textfile (the .prn one) you can type:

```
mytext = get_data_text(9, 2012)  # this time let's get the text for September, 2012 
print mytext[0]
```

that returns:

```
    MONTHLY STATEMENT OF THE PUBLIC DEBT
```

Comment: just want to say this was the most amazing answer I ever received, I learned a lot from it and still use the script on a week to monthly basis. Thanks furins

Comment: You are very kind to let me know about that! I'm glad that my answer helped you!